# How to create a generic RecyclerView.Adapter with Kotlin

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I created a Java class that extends RecyclerView.Adapter. It is generic and can accept any RecyclerView.ViewHolder class of SwipeableViewHolder type: Here is how its defined:

```
public abstract class SwipeableAdapter<T extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<T> {

     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(T holder, int position) {
        SwipeableViewHolder viewHolder = (SwipeableViewHolder) holder;

        ...
     }

}
```

This all works fine. However, when I try to convert it to Kotlin, I get an error in the onBindViewHolder function:

```
abstract class SwipeableAdapter<T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(protected var mContext: Context) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<T>() {    

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: T, position: Int) {

            val viewHolder = holder as SwipeableViewHolder

            ...
    }

}
```

Here is the SwipeableViewHolder class

```
open inner class SwipeableViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        @BindView(R.id.text_roll) internal var text_1: TextView? = null
        @BindView(R.id.text_trade) internal var text_2: TextView? = null
        @BindView(R.id.text_delete) internal var text_2: TextView? = null

        init {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView)
        }
    }
```

I get an error when I try to cast holder as SwipeableViewHolder. The error is: "One type argument expected. Use SwipeableViewHolder<*> if you don't want to pass type arguements"

I've tried so many different ways to implement this and just can't seem to figure it out.

Android Studio version : 3.5.3
KOtlin plugin compiler: 1.3

Comment: You say it can accept any type of ViewHolder, but won't it throw a ClassCastException if you pass it anything that isn't a SwipeableViewHolder?

Comment: @Tenfour04 . Yes you are correct. It can accept any RecyclerView.ViewHolder class of SwipeableViewHolder type. I have updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `SwipeableViewHolder` is an *inner* class of `SwipeableAdapter` (which requires a type argument), you have to specify what the type argument for `SwipeableAdapter` is as part of your cast:

```
val viewHolder = holder as SwipeableAdapter<*>.SwipeableViewHolder
```

Comment: No, you would think that though based on the error thrown though. I added the SwipeableViewHolder above for reference

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into my IDE and I can't reproduce this issue. What class is `SwipeableViewHolder` nested inside of? Is `SwipeableAdapter` also defined in that class? I had to qualify the cast (like `FooActivity.SwipeableViewHolder`); do you have anything like that?

Comment: .SwipeableViewHolder is inside of SwipeableAdapter

Comment: Ben P, your comment about qualifying the cast led me in the right direction. It should be:  val viewHolder = holder as SwipeableAdapter<T>.SwipeableViewHolder. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Since it only handles `SwipeableViewHolder` type ViewHolders, you should change the generic type bound. Then you don't even need to cast.

```
abstract class SwipeableAdapter<T : SwipeableViewHolder>(protected var mContext: Context) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<T>() {    

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: T, position: Int) {

            // just use holder since it is already known to be a SwipeableViewHolder
    }

}
```